# Configuring nexus lifecycle as part of the maven build

Tags: maven, nexus, devops, sonatype

I'm trying to configure my Maven build to run the nexus lifecycle (Sonatype clm), so far I have added the following to my projects pom:

```
<build>
    <pluginManagement>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.sonatype.clm</groupId>
                <artifactId>clm-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.6.0-01</version>
                <configuration>
                    <serverUrl>http://localhost:8070</serverUrl>
                    <applicationId>test</applicationId>
                    <stage>develop</stage>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
</build>
```

I have then added to the settings.xml file in my ${User.home}/.m2 folder:

```
<servers>
    <server>
         <id>nexus-site</id>
         <username>nexus_username</username>
         <password>nexus_password</password>
    </server>
</servers>
```

The issue I have had so far is that when I try to run the command:
`mvn package clm:evaluate -DskipTests`, I get a build failure. The error I get is:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal com.sonatype.clm:clm-maven-plugin:2.6.0-01:evaluate (default-cli) on project backend: Could not save module scan to C:\Users\user\git\backend\target\sonatype-clm\scan.xml.gz: Unauthorized -> [Help 1]
```

Has anyone got any ideas what this could be and how I could go about fixing it? Thanks in advance.

Comment: It's possible that this isn't really an authorization error. Try upgrading to the latest version of the plugin (2.7.0-01), we've improved our logging, if the cause is something else you'll be able to see it now.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like an authentication problem. As mentioned in the documentation you need to add the `serverId` tag to your configuration in the `pom` file -

> clm.serverId
>   used for authentication and must match the id given to the CLM Server specified in your Maven settings

**EDIT**:
Try to run the same command with the configuration mentioned below:

```
<build>
    <pluginManagement>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.sonatype.clm</groupId>
                <artifactId>clm-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.6.0-01</version>
                <configuration>
                    <serverUrl>http://localhost:8070</serverUrl>
                    <stage>develop</stage>
                    <applicationId>test</applicationId>
                    <serverId>nexus-site</serverId>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>evaluate</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
</build>
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this did not work and returns the same error, thank you for your help though.

Comment: Hey, look at my edit and tell me if you still getting the same error